# WPFMediaKit HDMI Capture card no sound

Tags: wpf-mediakit

I'm using WPFMediaKit for my school project to capture video from HDMI USB Capture card. However there is no sound, it can display the screen only.

How to activate the sound/audio from the HDMI signal ?

On the other hand, Can I record selected portion of the screen with audio signal, 
and saved to wmv/mp4 file ?

Thanks very much !

Comment: I have same project style (WPF MediaKit + HDMI), however I have not yet display video successfully. Could you please tell me the way to configure?